# Installing node http-proxy

Tags: sockets, node.js, real-time, npm

I am trying to install [node http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy/blob/master/README.md) with the following:

`npm install http-proxy`

But I get this error:

```
npm ERR! Unsupported
npm ERR! Not compatible with your version of node/npm: http-proxy@0.5.7
npm ERR! Required: {"node":"= 0.4.7"}
npm ERR! Actual:   {"npm":"1.0.6","node":"v0.5.0-pre"}
npm ERR!
npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.18-028stab070.14
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "http-proxy"
```

It says that it is unsupported with my version of Node.js. But I have v0.5.0 installed which is above the necessary v0.4.7.

Is node http-proxy only compatible with v0.4.7? Any ideas?

Comment: I'm guessing it's the 'v' in 'v0.5.0-pre' but I'm not sure how npm manages all that.

Comment: I should point out that the latest version of http-proxy works with 0.6 and up.  And there are a ton of fixes for adding proxies and discordant (https front and http back) proxying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd assume it's because the package.json for that module specifies a specific version of node (`"engines": { "node": "= 0.4.7" }`) as opposed to saying (`>= 0.4.7`). By contrast, the package.json for connect says `"engines": { "node": ">= 0.4.1 < 0.5.0" }`